# how do i center align images on a mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am creating a basic mobile version for a website. In the contact page I have the facebook & linkedin logo side by side. They are center aligned when viewed vertically. When the screen is rotated (in a iphone) the facebook logo moves to the left and is not centered. below is the link to the page.

http://www.prithvichandra.com/lennox/mobile/contact.html

all help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I don't see your problem. Both Facebook and LinkedIn logos are in a div and it is centered on my iPhone 4s, vertically or horizontally.

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this css can fix :

```
/*
.social-network-wrapper{ width:95%; margin: 10px 5%; float:left;}
.fb-wrapper, .ld-wrapper{ width:29%; float:left; text-align:center;}
*/
.social-network-wrapper {float: left; width: 100%;}
.fb-wrapper, .ld-wrapper{ width:48%;}
.fb-wrapper{text-align:right; float: left;}
.ld-wrapper{text-align:left; float: right;}
```

And change this line :

```
<div class="fb-wrapper" style="margin-left: 72px;">
```

to

```
<div class="fb-wrapper">
```